# Selective Repeat number of acknowledgements

Tags: algorithm, networking, tcp

I've been trying to solve a question that uses selective repeat protocol but I cant seem to figure it out.

what is the maximum number of different acknowledgements messages that can be propagating?

or in the specific example, window size of 13 with sequence number from 1-211. in time t the last packet in the senders window has sequence number 171. assume that medium does not reorder messages in both directions. what is the maximum number of ACK messages with different sequence numbers that are currently propagating back from the receiver to sender at time t ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This question presupposes a lot of information about networking that most programmers don't have.  I would suggest either summarizing the necessary facts about tcp or asking on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ah okay thank you :)